# Subversion equivalent to Git's 'show' command?

Tags: svn, git, version-control

I like how you can see what went into a git with `git show rev`

I haven't found an equivalent in Subversion. It seems Subversion wants you to do a diff between two commits to get anything reasonable.

Am I mistaken, or is there an equivalent to git show in svn to just see what went into a commit?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`svn diff -c rev` will show what changes happened in the specified revision.

`svn log --diff -c rev` will show the diff and the commit information.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to see not the list of files in the commit, but the contents of a file itself as it was in the commit.  You can do this with `svn cat -r rev filename`, where "rev" is the revision number and "filename" is the path or URL to the file.  Check `svn help cat` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`svn diff -c <commit>` will show you the actual changes made by a commit, but unlike git show it won't include the commit metadata.

What I ended up using to get something roughly equivalent to git show was

`( svn log -c <commit> ; svn diff -c <commit> )`

Comment: You could also use `svn log --diff -c <commit>`.